# TLC5947 with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, led

I have been trying to get 8 RGB leds to work with a [TLC5947](https://learn.adafruit.com/tlc5947-tlc59711-pwm-led-driver-breakout/overview) driver using a Raspberry Pi. But I am not able to get the leds to work.

I have tried with the help of fpulse from Wrobbel. But this did not work, maybe there are some settings wrong on the RPi.

I also converted the Library code the people at Adafruit used with an arduino. The pins from the driver are connected with the RPi in the following way:

- LAT->CE0
- /OE->GND
- CLK->CLK
- DIN->MOSI
- GND->GND
- V+->3V3

I am doing something wrong? Is there some setting that most be set on the RPi? Any tips would be welcome because for the moment I don't know how to get any further.

Comment: Do both the Adafruit module and the encapsulated TLC5947 work from 3V3 logic?

Comment: @joan the datasheet of the TLC5947 indeed says that it should be compatible with voltages between 3 and 5.5. http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/tlc5947.pdf

Comment: Adafruit repeatedly mention 5V+ for the module.  That might just be because it's targeted at Arduino.  You could try my [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) (needs [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/)) to monitor the signals.

Comment: @joan I have changed the connection of the V+ pin to 5V. But it didn't change anything immediatly. Now I will look into the piscope application, than I can at least monitor the signal. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a solution with the TLC5947. But I was able to get my leds to work with a [MCP23017](https://www.adafruit.com/product/732) module.

@joan thanks for looking into this.